Incorrect Doctor's Image Thumbnail Showing in SERP
I'm facing an issue with our orthopedic specialty page, and I would appreciate some guidance from the community. We have a dedicated page listing our orthopedic doctors, including both senior doctors and consultants.
When users search for the keyword "best knee replacement surgeon in Noida" Google's SERP is showing an image of one of our consultant doctors instead of one of our senior doctors.

I also checked in other search term like "best orthopedic surgeon in noida" no image is showing, which is OK, but it should show one of the senior doctor photo instead.
ACTUAL IMAGE SHOWING ON GOOGLE

CORRECT IMAGE TO SHOW ON GOOGLE SERP

Steps Taken So Far:

I have added words like knee replacement in senior doctor's
designation in that page
Also add related words to senior doctor specific pages.
then, i used google search console's clear snippet tool to clear the
snippet till the next time Google reindexes the page. But still it
shows the same image on SERP.

Despite these efforts, the desired image is still not showing up in the SERP. I'm looking for advice on any additional steps I can take to ensure the senior doctor's image is displayed when users search for "best knee replacement surgeon in Noida."

This can be an issue with a simple featured Image or Schema Code. It's necessary to test to find the right problem.
Featured Image Test
Go to your page and add the featured image you want to show, then submit the page through Google Search Console and wait for 7 to 10 days and see how it appear.
Schema Code Test
This method only if the first above didn't work.
Normally Google choose images that are setup in the right size if you don't provide the right image. In other words, they will choose for you.
I check your link and the image you have setup for schema code it's rectangular, which is not what search engines wants.
I highly recommend you to go here https://validator.schema.org/
Add you link and you'll see the line of code 38

This is the image you need update. The challenge here is to find where that schema code is. It can be in the header or maybe it's installed through Google Tag Manager.
I hope this helps!

Hey, thanks for you reply. I tried your method and change OG image tag's image from rectangle size to square one, then I clear the snippet for wait for 1 days until it clear the snippet and then again reindex the page. But still it showing the same image thumbnail which was coming earlier.
Now what should I do now? I'm totally lost. Plz help!
